# Rotate a GameObject slowly on click on it

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this game object that I am trying to rotate 90 degrees.

How to make it rotate smoothly?

```c#
private void OnMouseDown()
{
   gameObject.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, -90));
}
```

Comment: your question is ambigous, do you want an animation of it rotating 90 degress, or do you want when they click it slowly rotates?  Either take the existing value and increment it slowly , or create a coroutine which LERPs an object 90 degrees

Comment: I want it to slowly rotates when they click on it

Comment: @ZayedUpal this is not a duplicate of that question, this can be solved with out coroutines

Comment: pseudo code: `var rotation = gameObject.transform.Rotation;
rotation = new Vector3(rotation.x, rotation.y, rotation.z + 1.0f) 
gameObject.transform.Rotate(rotation);` I don't remember the member names etc but that will slowly rotate, if you want to slowly rotate it 90 degress you need to follow the duplicate answer someone posted here

Comment: Thank you for you help guys. I incremented the value slowly and it works well now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) to slowly animate it.

```c#
float rotationAmount = .1f;
float delaySpeed = .1f;
private void OnMouseDown(){
    StartCoroutine(SlowSpin());
}
IEnumerator SlowSpin(){
    float count = 0;
    while(count <= 90){
        gameObject.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, rotationAmount));
        count += rotationAmount;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delaySpeed);
    }
}
```

Change the variables on lines 1 and 2 to suit your needs. However, don't set `delaySpeed` too high, otherwise your animation will become choppy.

Comment: Thank you! that's exactly what i want to do